# Como guardar imagen en una ubicación en un FTP

Tags: c#, sql-server

Requiero almacenar una imagen en una ubicación en un FTP, la imagen que deseo guardar la estoy obteniendo por medio de una consulta. La siguiente es la tabla de la cual obtengo mi imagen:

```
CREATE TABLE TBL_APP_OG_FOTOS (
    NOMBRE_FOTO VARCHAR(MAX),
    ID VARCHAR(9),
    FOTO IMAGE
)
```

El siguiente es el método por el cual obtengo mi imagen y la muestro en mi PictureBox:

```
private void btnObtener_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //Crear variable de tipo SqlConnection 
            SqlConnection connect = new SqlConnection("Server=;database=; User Id = ; Password = ");
            connect.Open();

            //Consulta a tabla donde se encuentran las fotos
            SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("SELECT FOTO FROM TBL_APP_OG_FOTOS WHERE NOMBRE_FOTO = '11'", connect);

            SqlDataAdapter dp = new SqlDataAdapter(command);

            DataSet ds = new DataSet("TBL_APP_OG_FOTOS");

            byte[] MisDatos = new byte[0];

            dp.Fill(ds, "TBL_APP_OG_FOTOS");

            DataRow myRow = ds.Tables["TBL_APP_OG_FOTOS"].Rows[0];

            MisDatos = (byte[])myRow["FOTO"];

            MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(MisDatos);


            //Establecemos PictureBox
            pbVista.Image = Image.FromStream(ms);

           
        }
```

Ahora lo que requiero es almacenar la imagen en una ubicación en mi FTP después de obtenerla, alguien tiene idea de como lo puedo realizar.

**ACTUALIZACIÓN:**

Estoy haciendo uso de la clase `WebCLient` para la carga de documentos en el FTP

```
using (var client = new WebClient())
            {
                client.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("user", "pass");
                client.UploadFile("ftp://192.168.0.1", WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFile, localFile);
            }
```

Pero este me indica agregar como parámetro `localfile`, la imagen que deseo subir al FTP es la que obtengo en el método anterior por medio de la consulta, la imagen se encuentra en el campo `FOTO` de la tabla `TBL_APP_OG_FOTOS`

Anexo el error que me muestra a continuación:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**ACTUALIZACIÓN 2:**

Hice uso del método `UploadData` tal como lo menciona en los comentarios y en una de las respuestas pero aun no se logra almacenar mi archivo en el FTP correspondiente.

```
using (var client = new WebClient())
            {
                client.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("user", "pass");
                client.UploadData("192.168.0.1", MisDatos);
            }
```

Anexo imagen del código a continuación:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: aqui tienes un respuesta en el site [stackoverflow ingles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15268760/upload-file-to-ftp-using-c-sharp)

Comment: @Bryro Ya había visto la respuesta que me comentas, pero como le indico que se guarde en el FTP la imagen que anteriormente obtuve ?

Comment: la respuesta no es simplemente pasar la imagen a un byte[] y hacer uploaddata?

Comment: @gbianchi La respuesta me indica guardar la imagen local, es lo que quiero evitar, con el método que tengo en mi pregunta obtengo la imagen por medio de una consulta, ahora lo que requiero es que la imagen que obtuve se guarde en una ubicación en un FTP.

Comment: por eso pregunto. El metodo Upload tiene varias versiones, una sube data desde un array de bytes que es algo similar a lo que tenes.. eso lo probaste?

Comment: Si te refieres al método `UploadFile` de la clase `WebClient`, en mi actualización hice uso de ella tal como lo muestro pero esta me indica un error que también esta adjunto en una imagen

Comment: la clase WebCliente tiene le metodo [UploadData](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.webclient.uploaddata?view=net-5.0#System_Net_WebClient_UploadData_System_Uri_System_Byte___) que justamente sube un array de bytes en memoria a un servidor... eso trato de decirte... si ese metodo no es tu respuesta...

Comment: @gbianchi Sabes como puedo hacer uso del método `UploadData`, puedes agregarlo por favor a una respuesta para darle validez

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/116120/discussion-between-john-doe-and-gbianchi).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Agrego método para subir imágenes por ftp sin guardarla en local. Como parámetro recibe el arreglo de bytes a subir y el nombre del archivo. Solo se debe actualizar la dirección del servidor y el nombre de usuario y contraseña.

```
  static void SubirFTP(byte[] byteArray, string nombreArchivo){

    FtpWebRequest request = (FtpWebRequest)
    // reemplazar dirección ftp
    WebRequest.Create($"ftp://ftp.com/{nombreArchivo}");

   request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFile;

   request.Credentials = 
   // reemplazar user y password
   new NetworkCredential("user","password");

   Stream ftpStream = request.GetRequestStream();

   ftpStream.Write(byteArray,0,byteArray.Length);
   ftpStream.Close();

  }
```

Adaptado al método `btnObtener_Click` quedaría así:

```
private void btnObtener_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //Crear variable de tipo SqlConnection 
            SqlConnection connect = new SqlConnection("Server=;database=; User Id = ; Password = ");
            connect.Open();

            //Consulta a tabla donde se encuentran las fotos
            SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("SELECT FOTO,NOMBRE_FOTO FROM TBL_APP_OG_FOTOS WHERE NOMBRE_FOTO = '11'", connect);

            SqlDataAdapter dp = new SqlDataAdapter(command);

            DataSet ds = new DataSet("TBL_APP_OG_FOTOS");

            byte[] MisDatos = new byte[0];

            dp.Fill(ds, "TBL_APP_OG_FOTOS");
            
            DataRow myRow = ds.Tables["TBL_APP_OG_FOTOS"].Rows[0];

            MisDatos = (byte[])myRow["FOTO"];
            string nombreImagen = (string)myRow["NOMBRE_FOTO"];

            // subida a servidor ftp
            SubirFTP(MisDatos,nombreImagen);

            MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(MisDatos);


            //Establecemos PictureBox
            pbVista.Image = Image.FromStream(ms);

           
        }
```

---

**Actualización**

Código para leer todas las imágenes y subirlas al servidor:

```
public static void Cargar()
        {
            var con = new SqlConnection("");
            con.Open();

            var command = con.CreateCommand();
            
            command.CommandText = "SELECT FOTO, NOMBRE_FOTO FROM TBL_APP_OG_FOTOS";

            var reader = command.ExecuteReader();
            
            // leer las filas
            while(reader.Read()){
                // extraer nombre de la imagen y la imagen
               var nombreImagen =  reader.GetString("NOMBRE_FOTO");
               var imagen  = reader.GetSqlBytes(0).Value;
               // subir imagen
               SubirFTP(imagen,nombreImagen);
            }

            reader.Close();
            con.Close();


        }
```

Llamar el método `Cargar()` desde `btnObtener_Click`:

```
private void btnObtener_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  Cargar();
}
```

Comment: Solo me queda duda en esta respuesta como agregar como parámetro el nombre del archivo, si se refiere al nombre de la imagen esta se obtiene de la columna `NOMBRE_FOTO` de la tabla `TBL_APP_OG_FOTOS`.

Comment: Puedes agregar `NOMBRE_FOTO `a la consulta SQL y después leerla como haces con `FOTO`. Actualicé la respuesta con el ejemplo. Aunque veo que filtras por `NOMBRE_FOTO = 11`, me da la impresión que ya sabes cual será el nombre de la imagen, de ser así ese sería el parámetro del método `SubirFTP()`.

Comment: Tengo duda con la dirección FTP, esta se agrega con el prefijo ftp://(dirección) o solo dirección ?

Comment: Con el prefijo. Este es un ejemplo de una url de  servidor ftp público: `ftp://speedtest.tele2.net/`

Comment: Efectivamente guardo el archivo pero sin extensión, hace falta agregar algo mas en la respuesta ?

Comment: La extensión debe ir en el parámetro `nombreArchivo` por ejemplo  `imagen.jpg`. Creo que ya no hace falta nada más en la respuesta.

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/116131/discussion-between-john-doe-and-lobos).